# How to rename a specific range of columns in Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
 KOAK.rename(columns = lambda x : 'KOAK-' + x, inplace=True)
```

The above code allows me to add 'KOAK' in front of all column headers in my data frame but I only want to add the KOAK prefix to column numbers 4-38. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are these column numbers the names or the ordinal positions?

Comment: They were the position, not the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign to `columns`:

```
KOAK.columns = ['KOAK-' + x if 4 <= i <= 38 else x for i, x in enumerate(KOAK.columns, 1)]
```

Example:

```
KOAK = pd.DataFrame(dict.fromkeys('ABCDEFG', [12]))
KOAK.columns = ['KOAK-' + x if 2 <= i <= 4 else x 
                for i, x in enumerate(KOAK.columns, 1)]
print(KOAK)
```

Prints:

```
    A  KOAK-B  KOAK-C  KOAK-D   E   F   G
0  12      12      12      12  12  12  12
```

Comment: don't you need to cast `x` to a `str` if the column names are ints which they maybe in the OP's case?

Comment: `x` is a string because `x in KOAK.columns`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Not necessarily, it's possible to have ints as column names: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0,1,2,3,4])` then `df.columns.tolist()` returns: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Well, the OP does `'KOAK-' + x` in the `lambda` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dict by zipping the column ordinal range with a list comprehension and passing this to `rename`:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcdefg'))
df

Out[2]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
Index: []

In [3]:
new_cols = dict(zip(df.columns[2:5], ['KOAK-' + x for x in df.columns[2:5]]))
new_cols

Out[3]:
{'c': 'KOAK-c', 'd': 'KOAK-d', 'e': 'KOAK-e'}

In [6]:    
df.rename(columns= new_cols, inplace=True)
df

Out[6]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, KOAK-c, KOAK-d, KOAK-e, f, g]
Index: []
```

so in your care the following should work:

```
new_cols = dict(zip(df.columns[3:47], ['KOAK-' + str(x) for x in df.columns[3:47]]))
df.rename(columns= new_cols, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This answer got me what I wanted as well. Thank you.